# rosbag info in C++

Tags: c++, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to get the names of all the topics in a rosbag in C++ (that is using something like rosbag API). The rosbag [cookbook](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook) mentions how to get information about the rosbag using python but not C++.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39345/rosbag-info-in-c++/) by [Ankush](https://answers.ros.org/users/2890/ankush/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use rosbag::View::getConnectionInfo.

```
rosbag::Bag bag("foo.bag");
rosbag::View view(bag);
std::vector<const rosbag::ConnectionInfo *> connection_infos = view.getConnectionInfo();
std::set<std::string> topics;

BOOST_FOREACH(const rosbag::ConnectionInfo *info, connection_infos) {
  if( !topics.find(info->topic) ) {
    topics.insert(info->topic);
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ankush](https://answers.ros.org/users/2890/ankush/) on 2012-07-20**:
Thank you, that really helped. On the same note, what is the C++ equivalent of "rewriting bag", given in the cookbook (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook)?

I want to process a particular topic from a rosbag file and write the others unchanged to a new bagfile.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code proposed by Lorenz did not compile! This is what it should be after fixing the errors:

```
rosbag::Bag bag("foo.bag");
rosbag::View view(bag);
std::vector<const rosbag::ConnectionInfo *> connection_infos = view.getConnections();
std::set<std::string> topics;

BOOST_FOREACH(const rosbag::ConnectionInfo *info, connection_infos) {
  topics.insert(info->topic);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [beginner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22256/beginner/) with karma: 83 on 2015-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2020-01-08**:
So how do we print them in terminal? maybe  `cout << info->topic << "\t[" << info->datatype << "]" << endl;` inside `BOOST_FOREACH` function?